# How to display BusyIndicator in a ComboBox

Tags: silverlight, busyindicator

I am using Silverlight 5 with WCF Ria Services. For fast development I coded a provider based system to populate ComboBoxes. When I set provider for a combo and bind EditValue to ViewModel everything works perfectly.

```
<Controls:BLComboBoxEdit2 x:Name="cbeDepartmentId" 
  EditValue="{Binding Path=Selected.DepartmentId, Mode=TwoWay" 
  ComboDataProvider="{Binding Path=DepartmentComboDataProvider}" />
```

But in order to notify user while combo is waiting for data to be loaded by provider I needed a BusyIndicator. I could not figure out how to show BusyIndicator in inherited control (we could do this back in WinForm days by overriding OnPaint events etc.) so I created a UserControl, xaml is like this (we are using DevExpress ComboBoxEdit),

```
<UserControl ...>

<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../Assets/Styles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <dxe:ComboBoxEdit x:Name="combo" />
    <toolkit:BusyIndicator x:Name="busyIndicator" Style="{StaticResource AjaxBusyIndicator}"
            IsBusy="{Binding Path=ComboDataProvider.IsWorking}">
    </toolkit:BusyIndicator>
</Grid>
```

and it looks like this,

[image: combos on work]

In some scenarios (for grid columns etc.) we needed a ComboBoxEdit derived control, not a UserControl. So I started to modify the code, but I am stuck. I don't know how to add a child control (or overlay control?) to be shown when the control is busy.

```
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit ...>

<dxe:ComboBoxEdit.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../Assets/Styles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <Common:PublicStrings x:Key="ResourceStrings" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</dxe:ComboBoxEdit.Resources>

<Grid>
    <toolkit:BusyIndicator x:Name="busyIndicator" Style="{StaticResource AjaxBusyIndicator}"
            IsBusy="{Binding Path=ComboDataProvider.IsWorking}" />
</Grid>
```

When I run the above code, combo works normally but busy indicator is not shown (as expected from this code, busy indicator becomes content of the combo, if I popup the combo [while loading in progress] I can see the BusyIndicator :) but after first load, it disappears because content has changed).

Is there a way to do this? Now I am trying to set content at code behind (after IsBusy changed I want to set the content to a BusyIndicator or leave as default), but no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try  to put both the controls means the combobox and busyindicator into the same place like onto the same column of the Grid and make IsBusy= true(having same height and weight for both) before the async call and change it to false on completed event
2. Put the comboBox Inside the BusyIndicator as content

   ```
    <toolkit:BusyIndicator x:Name="busyIndicator" Style="{StaticResource AjaxBusyIndicator}" IsBusy="{Binding Path=ComboDataProvider.IsWorking}">
      <ComboBox/>
   </toolkit:BusyIndicator>
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.In fact I am using this approach (you may see in above code,combo and busyindicator are in same grid row),and I converted it to a user control (BLComboBoxEdit) to avoid writing BusyIndicator for every combo usage,but this way the control's type is UserControl.I need ComboBoxEdit derived control to use in some cases.When deriving from ComboBoxEdit I realized I don't know where to put BusyIndicator xaml.If I write it directly it becames content. I need BusyIndicator to be shown as overlay on the combo.By the way,priority has changed for this question,now it is not a must :)